# Node.js http Request timeout error

Tags: node.js, npm, request

I'm using npm request module to call an http api. It's working for 1 url but not working for same domain other url, everytime I'm getting timeout. same url is working in postman. What could be the reason ?

```
 var request = require("request");
    const url1 = 'http://example.com/xyz';
    const url2 = 'http://example.com/jkl';
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Host: 'example.com',
            'User-Agent': 'request'
        }
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(body);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle timeout issues, you can choose the following way:

```
var options = {
    url:  'http://your_url',
    timeout: 120000 // you can set this value as per your needs
}

request(options, function(err, resp, body) {});
```

Comment: I tried this also, In postman it's giving response in less than one second.

Comment: which url are you using in option? url1 or url2

Comment: timeout <number> Milliseconds before a request times out.

Comment: you can set timeout value in options as per required